# Fiksu SDK Integration in ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to implement Fiksu SDK for iOS application with swift programming

I have dowloaded Fiksu SDK framework and also added in my iOS application

I have demo code which is in objective-c, can any one help me to convert in swift so i can use in my application

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication )application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary )launchOptions {

// original code ...

    [FiksuTrackingManager applicationDidFinishLaunching:launchOptions
                                        configuration:@{    
#ifdef DEBUG // You don't want this to show up in your release builds
      FiksuTrackingConfigurationDebugModeEnabledKey : @(YES),
#endif
      FiksuTrackingConfigurationAppIdentifierKey : @"123456789"
    }];

// original code ...

     return YES;
}
```

And after that what will be process and which event should i use
if any one has implemented it please guide me how to proceed ?

Comment: i am working on the same i had a same problem can any please help me to solve these